# Problem while reading the value of Code from XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, parsing, soap

Here is the xml

```
string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
<UserMLogin xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"> 
<Code>1</Code>
<Message>success</Message>
<Name>athil</Name>  
</UserMLogin>";
```

What I tried

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml.ToString());
XmlNodeList nodes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/Code");
```

What i got

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><UserMLogin xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">  <Code>1</Code>  <Message>success</Message>  <Name>athil</Name></UserMLogin>
```

What I am expecting

```
1
```

Comment: You haven't shown how you're *trying* to read the values, which makes it harder to help you. I'd suggest using LINQ to XML though (XDocument) as it's a much simpler to use API. I'd suggest starting by reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview, then try applying that, and edit your question to show what you've tried and where you're stuck (if you *are* still stuck).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `SelectSingleNode` with `NameSpace`

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml.ToString());

XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", "http://tempuri.org/");
string code = doc.SelectSingleNode("/ns:UserMLogin/ns:Code", nsmgr).InnerText;
```

Comment: Not working because of namespace

Comment: updated the post by adding namespace